# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: No properties to serialize found on class com.sale.organiccrops.organiccropsonsale.CartData

Tags: java, android

I am working on an Android application and I am getting the following error:

```
2019-05-05 18:19:35.582 9087-9087/com.sale.organiccrops.organiccropsonsale E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sale.organiccrops.organiccropsonsale, PID: 9087
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: No properties to serialize found on class com.sale.organiccrops.organiccropsonsale.CartData
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:535)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.loadOrCreateBeanMapperForClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:317)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:166)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.serialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:152)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToPlainJavaTypes(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:60)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValueInternal(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:292)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.1.0:166)
        at com.sale.organiccrops.organiccropsonsale.CheckoutActivity$2.onClick(CheckoutActivity.java:64)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6304)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24803)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:794)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6635)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

The Java code of CheckoutActivity is:

```
package com.sale.organiccrops.organiccropsonsale;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Objects;
public class CheckoutActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText address;
    private DatabaseReference reference;
    private TextView amount;
    private Double sum;
    private ArrayList<CartData> data;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_checkout);
        amount = findViewById(R.id.amount);
        address = findViewById(R.id.address);
        data = new ArrayList<>();
        Button confirm = findViewById(R.id.confirm);
        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null) {
            reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() + "/cart");
            reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    data.clear();
                    sum = 0.0;
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        data.add(new CartData(snapshot.child("english").getValue(String.class), snapshot.child("hindi").getValue(String.class), snapshot.child("quantity").getValue(String.class), snapshot.child("image").getValue(String.class), snapshot.child("price").getValue()));
                        sum += snapshot.child("price").getValue(Double.class);
                    }
                    amount.setText(new StringBuilder().append("₹ ").append(sum));
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
        }
        confirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (address.length() == 0) {
                    address.requestFocus();
                    address.setError("This Is A Required Field");
                } else {
                    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("admins/orders/pending").push();
                    reference.child("user").setValue(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
                    reference.child("address").setValue(address.getText().toString());
                    reference.child("items").setValue(data);
                    reference.child("price").setValue(Double.parseDouble(amount.getText().toString().replace("₹ ", "")));
                    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() + "/orders/ongoing").child(Objects.requireNonNull(reference.getKey()));
                    reference.child("address").setValue(address.getText().toString());
                    reference.child("items").setValue(data);
                    reference.child("price").setValue(Double.parseDouble(amount.getText().toString().replace("₹ ", ""))).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null) {
                                reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() + "/cart");
                                reference.removeValue().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Order Placed Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), UserDashboardActivity.class));
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), CartActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), AuthenticationActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), AuthenticationActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), AuthenticationActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

The Java code of CartData, CartActivity, and CartAdapter is:

```
package com.sale.organiccrops.organiccropsonsale;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Objects;
class CartData {
    private String english, hindi, quantity, url;
    private Object price;
    CartData(String english, String hindi, String quantity, String url, Object price) {
        this.english = english;
        this.hindi = hindi;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.url = url;
        this.price = price;
    }
    String getEnglish() {
        return english;
    }
    String getHindi() {
        return hindi;
    }
    String getQuantity() {
        return quantity;
    }
    String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
    Object getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    void setPrice(Object price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
public class CartActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ProgressBar progress;
    private ArrayList<CartData> data;
    private TextView products;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private Button checkout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_cart);
        progress = findViewById(R.id.progress);
        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        products = findViewById(R.id.products);
        checkout = findViewById(R.id.checkout);
        data = new ArrayList<>();
        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null) {
            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() + "/cart");
            reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    data.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        data.add(new CartData(snapshot.child("english").getValue(String.class), snapshot.child("hindi").getValue(String.class), snapshot.child("quantity").getValue(String.class), snapshot.child("image").getValue(String.class), snapshot.child("price").getValue()));
                    }
                    progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    if (data.isEmpty()) {
                        products.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        checkout.setEnabled(false);
                    } else {
                        products.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        checkout.setEnabled(true);
                        checkout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), CheckoutActivity.class));
                                finish();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
                    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getBaseContext()));
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(new CartAdapter(data));
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                }
            });
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), UserDashboardActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), AuthenticationActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        super.onRestart();
        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), AuthenticationActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(), AuthenticationActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }
}
class CartAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<CartData> data;
    private DatabaseReference reference;
    private String key;
    CartAdapter(ArrayList<CartData> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_cart, viewGroup, false));
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder viewHolder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int i) {
        viewHolder.english.setText(data.get(i).getEnglish());
        viewHolder.hindi.setText(data.get(i).getHindi());
        viewHolder.quantity.setText(data.get(i).getQuantity());
        viewHolder.price.setText(new StringBuilder().append("₹ ").append(data.get(i).getPrice()));
        GlideApp.with(viewHolder.image.getContext()).load(data.get(i).getUrl()).into(viewHolder.image);
        viewHolder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() != null) {
                    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() + "/cart");
                    reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                if (Objects.equals(snapshot.child("english").getValue(), data.get(i).getEnglish()) && Objects.equals(snapshot.child("hindi").getValue(), data.get(i).getHindi()) && Objects.equals(snapshot.child("quantity").getValue(), data.get(i).getQuantity()) && Objects.equals(snapshot.child("price").getValue(), data.get(i).getPrice())) {
                                    key = snapshot.getKey();
                                }
                            }
                            if (key != null) {
                                reference.child(key).removeValue();
                            }
                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }
    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView english, hindi, quantity, price;
        private ImageButton delete;
        private ImageView image;
        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.english = itemView.findViewById(R.id.english);
            this.hindi = itemView.findViewById(R.id.hindi);
            this.quantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
            this.price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            this.delete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
            this.image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }
    }
}
```

While installing the app using Android Studio, it is working fine. But after building the APK and installing the app using APK, it is giving the above error. Can someone please help me resolve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: show us your `CartData` class.

Comment: Added to the question. Please check and let me know if it helps or if any other things need to be added. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your CartData, you probably miss those set method.

```
void setEnglish() {
       this.english = english;
    }
```

Do the same thing for `Hindi`,`Quantity` and `Url`.